# Postgres generate_series and crosstab in query

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, crosstab, generate-series

I need a time series data but incorporate `generate_series` for times where there's no datapoint on the table. Also, a `crosstab` to pivot the records.

I have the `generate_series` for the time frame needed:

```
SELECT generate_series('2015-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2015-03-31 23:00'::timestamp,interval '1 hour')::timestamp
```

**but** i need help adding `generate_series` and `crosstab` to the query below:

```
SELECT   
    timestamp as timestamp_utc,
    id as auth_id,
    coalesce(value, 0) as market_price

FROM table1 t1

WHERE timestamp between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:55:00'
    AND id in (42,54,38,51)
```

**Problem:** some datapoints in `timestamp_utc` are missing and i would like to identify those using `generate_series`. Lastly `crosstab` the values of `AND t3.id in (42,54,38,51)` in a column pivot.

Sample outcome should look like:

```
timestamp_utc      | 42    |54    |38    |51    |
-------------------|-------|------|------|------|
2015-01-01 01:00:00| 252.45| 0    | 1231 | 141.2|
2015-01-01 02:00:00| 0     | 112.3| 0    | 245.1|
2015-01-01 03:00:00| 0     | 234.1| 0    | 143.6|
```

Thanks for any help